# Handling multiple subprotocols with System.Net.WebSockets

Tags: c#, .net, windows, websocket

What is the correct way for a WebSockets server using `HttpListener` and [System.Net.WebSockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to support multiple subprotocols?

I am using `HttpListener` to create an `HttpListenerContext`. On receiving a request with `IsWebSocketRequest` true the code calls [`AcceptWebSocketAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenercontext.acceptwebsocketasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the subprotocol name as the parameter.

If the client request is for a different subprotocol then an exception is raised, which is to be expected.

There's no version of `AcceptWebSocketAsync()` that accepts a list of subprotocols and if I make two asynchronous calls to `AcceptWebSocketAsync()` with different subprotocols, only the latter is effective.

#### Edit 14 March

To clarify, I'm looking for support for the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header such that the framework accepts a websockets upgrade based on finding a common subprotocol between those requested by the client and those supported by the server, and then tells the calling code in some way which (single) subprotocol has been agreed. (For example, in [libwebsockets](https://libwebsockets.org/), you provide one callback per subprotocol.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have access to `HttpListenerContext` which has the `Request` property. It returns an instance of `HttpListenerRequest` which in turn has the `Headers` property. `Headers` returns a collection of name/value pairs. You should find there **Sec-WebSocket-Protocol** header.

Now you have the list of subprotocols requested by a client. You also know what subprotocols are known by a server so you easily perform matching.

However, to be honest I didn't try this approach and I'm aware that it is not a straightforward solution.

Comment: @Ian Goldby - I updated my answer. I hope that it'll be useful.

Comment: @Ian Goldby - No problem. Initially, I didn't understand your question correctly.